# Storing and accessing a large number of relatively small files

Tags: database, performance, storage

I am running lots of very slow computations with reusable results (and often computing something new relies on a computation that was already performed before). To make use of them, I want to store the results somewhere (permanently). The computations can be uniquely identified by two identifiers: experiment name and computation name, and the value is an array of floats (which I currently store as raw binary data). They need to be individually accessed (read and written) by experiment and computation name very often, and sometimes also just by experiment name (i.e. all computations with their results for a given experiment). They are also sometimes concatenated, but if reading and writing is fast, no additional support for this operation is needed. This data will not need to be accessed for any web application (used only by non-production scripts that need the results of the computations, but calculating them each time is not feasible), and there is no need for transactions, but every write needs to be atomic (e.g. turning off the computer should not result in corrupted/partial data). Reading also needs to be atomic (e.g. if two processes try to access a result of one computation, and it's not there, so one of them starts saving the new result, the other process should either receive it when it's done, or receive nothing at all). Accessing the data remotely is not required, but helpful.

So, TL;DR requirements:

- permanent storage of binary data (no metadata other than the identifier needs to be stored)
- very fast access (read/write) based on a compound identifier
- ability to read all data by one part of a compound identifier
- concurrent, atomic read/write
- no need for transactions, complex queries, etc.
- remote access would be nice to have, but not required
- the whole thing is there mostly to save time, so speed is critical

The solutions I tried so far are:

- storing them as individual files (one directory per experiment, one binary file per computation) - requires manual handling of atomicity, and also most file systems support file names only up to 255 characters long (and computation names may be longer than that), so an additional mapping would be required; also I'm not sure if ext4 (which is the filesystem I'm using and can't change it) is designed to handle millions of files
- using a sqlite database (with just one table and a compound primary key) - at first it seemed perfect, but when we got to hundreds of gigabytes of data (millions of ~100 KB blobs, and both number of them and their size will increase), it started being really slow, even after applying optimizations found on the internet

Naturally, after sqlite failed, the first idea was to just move to a "proper" database like postgres, but then I realized that perhaps in this case a relational database is not really the way to go (especially since speed is critical here, and I don't need most of their features) - and especially postgres is probably not the way to go, since the closest thing to a blob is bytea, which requires additional conversions (so a perfomance hit is guaranteed). However, after researching a bit about key-value databases (which seemed to apply to my problem), I found out that all of the databases that I checked do not support compound keys, and often have length limitations for keys (e.g. couchbase has just 250 bytes). So, should I just go with a normal relational database, try one of NoSQL databases, or maybe something completely different like HDF5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up using a relational database anyway (since only there I could use compound keys without any hacks).
I performed a benchmark to compare sqlite with postgres and mysql - 500 000 inserts of ~60 KB blobs and then 50 000 selects by the whole key. This was not enough to slow down sqlite to the unacceptable levels I was experiencing, but set a point of reference (i.e. the speed at which sqlite was running with this few records was acceptable to me). I assumed that I wouldn't experience a huge performance hit when adding more records with mysql and postgres (since they were designed to work with much larger amounts of data than sqlite), and when finally using one of them, that turned out to be true.

The settings (other than defaults) were following:

- sqlite: journal mode=wal (required for parallel access), isolation level autocommit, values as `BLOB`
- postgres: isolation level autocommit (can't turn off transactions, and doing everything in one huge transaction was not an option for me), values as `BYTEA` (which sadly includes the double conversion I wrote about)
- mysql: engine=aria, transactions disabled, values as `MEDIUMBLOB`

As you can see, I was able to customize mysql much more to fit the task at hand. The results below reflect it well:

```
                     sqlite     postgres        mysql
selects           90.816292   191.910514   106.363534
inserts         4367.483822  7227.473075  5081.281370
```

Mysql had similar speed to sqlite, with postgres being significantly slower.

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve on the database solution is to externalize the data blob.

You can use SeaweedFS https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs as an object store, upload the blob and get an file id, and then store the file id in the database. (I am working on SeaweedFS)

This should reduce the database load quite a bit, and querying will be much faster.